# Images dissappear when viewing on phone

Tags: html, css

Currently I am trying to make a social button visible but different from desktop view. My HTML is:

```css
#facebook {
    position: fixed;
    top: 47vw;
    left: 50vw;
}
    
#facebook img {
    width: auto; 
    height: 1.25vw;
    position: absolute;
}
    
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #facebook img { 
        width: auto; 
        height: 4.5vw;
        position: absolute;
    }

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #facebook { 
        top: 160vw;
        left: 50vw;
    }
}
```

```html
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">
    <div id="facebook">
        <img class="fb" src="images/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" />
    </div>
</a>
```

Edit: Fixed it by changing the vw to a percentage

Answer (score 1):

Your error lies in:

```
#facebook { 
    top: 160vw;
    left: 50vw;
}
```

change it to:

```
#facebook { 
    top: 0vw;
    left: 0vw;
}
```

Having the top at 160 viewport width will obviously move the entire thing off the screen

Comment: The edtior cut this part out: @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {

Answer (score 0):

I think your width: auto is causing the trouble!
Have you tried adding min-width and min-height?

```
 #facebook img {
 min-width: 20px;
 min-height: 20px;
 }
```

Comment: I have tried this but using this will cause the image to overlap other elements when I resize it on desktop

Answer (score 0):

`vw`    Relative to 1% of the width of the viewport* and
`vh`    Relative to 1% of the height of the viewport*

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   #facebook { 
     top: 160vw;
     left: 50vw;
   }
}
```

Here 160vw is too large that's why image goes outside of view port.